# Chromakey Conversion

Tags: opengl, gpu

I have a program I wrote that allows chromakey (green screen) using a web cam. I wrote it using DirectShow - I created a custom filter to blend the web cam video with a graphic. It works fine but requires huge amounts of CPU. Also, from what I understand, DS is deprecated - or at least on its way out.

So, I'm thinking about re-doing it with OpenGL and using OpenCV to grab the web cam video. I don't have a lot of experience with OpenGL, so my question is: If I create a chromakey shader will it be executed on the GPU and therefore be faster? Or is this something for which OpenGL is not useful?

I would like the input of someone with experience before I attempt this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It almost certainly depends on implementation. I have used CPU only keyers that had no problems keying full hd in real time.

But back to the question would a shader be faster? Most likely, especially if your chroma key is a classic color transform. Then the GPU would shine as it would get to use it massive multicore architecture to full potential.